# Authentication tokens expiring or being deleted after a page refresh

Tags: python, reactjs, django, jwt, djoser

I'm using using Django with Django Rest Framework for my backend API and DJOSER for authentication, along with the **djangorestframework_simplejwt **package for handling JSON Web Tokens (JWT). I have configured the token lifetimes in my settings.py file, but I've encountering issues with authentication tokens expiring or being deleted after a page refresh in my backend.

Here is my auth.js file from React:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
    USER_LOADED_FAIL,
    AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS,
    AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
    LOGOUT

} from './types';

export const checkAuthenticated = () => async (dispatch) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access')) {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
      };
  
      const body = JSON.stringify({ token: localStorage.getItem('access') });
  
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/verify/`,
          body,
          config
        );
        if (res.data.code !== 'token_not_valid') {
          dispatch({
            type: AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS,
          });
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
          type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
        });
      }
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
      });
    }
  };
  

  export const load_user = () => async (dispatch) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access')) {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      };
  
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`,
          config
        );
        dispatch({
          type: USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
          type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
        });
      }
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
      });
    }
  };
  
  

export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
  
    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
  
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/create/`,
        body,
        config
      );
      localStorage.setItem('access', res.data.access); // Store the access token in local storage
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
  
      dispatch(load_user());
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      });
    }
  };
  

export const logout = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT
    })
};
```

It handle authentication and user-related actions in my React application.

Login.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Navigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../actions/auth'
import axios from 'axios';

import backGround from '../img/fromAndrea.jpg';

import Home from "../containers/Home"

const Login = ({ login, isAuthenticated }) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });

    const { email, password } = formData;


    const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        login(email, password);
    };

    // Redirect home page
    if (isAuthenticated){
        console.log("AUTH success!")
        return <Navigate to="/" replace={true} />
    }

    return (
       Some HTML Code...
      )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
```

And here is my Home.js:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../actions/auth';

import LoggedInfrom "./Home/LoggedIn"
import NotLoggedInfrom "./Home/NotLoggedInfrom "

const Home = ({ logout, isAuthenticated }) => {

  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);


  const guestLinks = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <NotLoggedInfrom />
    </Fragment>
  );

  const authLinks = () => (
    <LoggedIn/>
  );

  return(
    <>
    <Fragment>
    {isAuthenticated ? authLinks() : guestLinks()}
    </Fragment>
    </>
  )

};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(Home);
```

And Finally here is my settings.py from backend:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',
    )
}

DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_TOKEN_STRATEGY': 'djoser.social.token.jwt.TokenStrategy',
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_ALLOWED_REDIRECT_URIS': ['http://localhost:8000/google', 'http://localhost:8000/facebook'],
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserAccount'
```

I have already checked the file paths, the URLs: /auth/jwt/create/, /auth/users/me/, /auth/jwt/verify/. All of them are working. I have checked the console, and no errors found. I have checked the local storage. The token has appeared in there, but the backend didn't get it for some reason. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

access state should get initial value from localStorage . you should put this in your redux access variable.

```js
localStorage.getItem('access')||null
```